# pipenv install django fail

Tags: django, pipenv

I am using pipenv to install django, but I get an Error.

```
    Usage: pipenv install [OPTIONS] [PACKAGES]...

    ERROR:: --system is intended to be used for pre-existing Pipfile installation, not installation of specific packages. Aborting.
```

Answer (score 6):

Before I try to create another project in the same directory that the last project exists, somehow, the last virtualenv was not deleted, so I look into other pipenv commands, and there is one `pipenv --rm` which helps Removing virtualenv that the last project left behind.

Comment: Saved me, I was going mad with that error. thanks

Comment: You are life saver was beating my head around this issue.